# Placing TabControl inside Grid gives an error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface

While creating a window in WPF,when trying to place TabControl inside Grid gives the following error:

> Error 1   Property elements cannot be in the middle of an element's
>   content. They must be before or after the content.

**Development Platform: Windows-7 : Visual Studio 2008**

XAML code:

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
x:Name="USBTOOL"
Title="Window1"
Height="768" Width="1300" ResizeMode="NoResize">

 <UserControl>
   <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="4,4,4,4" BorderBrush="#FF8C8E94" Background="#8C208AB0" Margin="8,20.66,10,0" Height="51" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextElement.FontWeight="Bold" TextElement.FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" TextElement.FontSize="18" TextElement.Foreground="#FF000000" OpacityMask="{x:Null}" x:Name="TopTitleMenu"/>
        <Border BorderThickness="1"
        CornerRadius="6,6,6,6" BorderBrush="#FF8C8E94" Background="#8C208AB0" Margin="8,76,10,10" TextElement.FontWeight="Bold" TextElement.FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" TextElement.FontSize="18" TextElement.Foreground="#FF000000" OpacityMask="{x:Null}"/>


    <Grid.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="-0.072,-0.118">
            <GradientStop Color="#FF132734" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF072E42" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>

        <TabControl>  </TabControl>

  </Grid>
 </UserControl>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TabControl it is not the problem. Problem is
`<Grid.Background>
...
</Grid.Background>`

Setting properties for Grid like this must occur before or after all content of Gird control.

Just move TabControl declaration above Grid.Background.

Comment: Thank You for the solution.